# How can I run an argparse python program without the .py extension?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, argparse

Currently, I have to type `/xkcdpwgen.py -h` in order to get the following

> usage: xkcdpwgen [-h] [-w WORDS] [-c CAPS] [-n NUMBERS] [-s SYMBOLS]
>
> Generate a secure, memorable password using the XKCD method
>
> optional arguments:   -h, --help            show this help message and
> exit   -w WORDS, --words WORDS
> include WORDS words in the password (default=4)   -c CAPS, --caps CAPS  capitalize the first letter of
> CAPS random words
> (default=0)   -n NUMBERS, --numbers NUMBERS
> insert NUMBERS random numbers in the password
> (default=0)   -s SYMBOLS, --symbols SYMBOLS
> insert SYMBOLS random symbols in the password
> (default=0)

But, I want to be able to type `/xkcdpwgen -h` and get the following

> usage: xkcdpwgen.py [-h] [-w WORDS] [-c CAPS] [-n NUMBERS] [-s
> SYMBOLS]
>
> Generate a secure, memorable password using the XKCD method
>
> optional arguments:   -h, --help            show this help message and
> exit   -w WORDS, --words WORDS
> include WORDS words in the password (default=4)   -c CAPS, --caps CAPS  capitalize the first letter of
> CAPS random words
> (default=0)   -n NUMBERS, --numbers NUMBERS
> insert NUMBERS random numbers in the password
> (default=0)   -s SYMBOLS, --symbols SYMBOLS
> insert SYMBOLS random symbols in the password
> (default=0)

Instead, I get the following

> bash: ./xkcdpwgen: No such file or directory

Comment: Rename it. There's no compelling reason for it to have an extension.

Comment: I did not know that was possible until I saw the answer below

Comment: You didn't know it was possible to rename a file, or didn't know that the script wasn't required to have a `.py` extension?

Comment: I didn't know that it was possible run the file without the .py extention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name it whatever you'd like; as long as the she-bang line (e.g. `#!/bin/python`) is good, then the file will run.

```
$ mv xkcdpwgen.py xkcdpwgen
$ ./xkcdpwgen -h
```

For more info: [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on Wikipedia